# How to interpret the sense of these phrases?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english, interpretation, learning

in the lyrics of Paul McCartney's song *This One*

https://genius.com/Paul-mccartney-this-one-lyrics

I am trying to interpret this:

> What opportunities did we allow to flow by
> Feeling like the timing wasn't quite right?
> What kind of magic might have worked if we had stayed calm?
> Couldn't I have given you a better life?

what I came up with is:

1 - What opportunities did we allow to flow by
Feeling like the timing wasn't quite right?

possible interpretation: did we pass over any opportunity even feeling it was not a good time?

2 - What kind of magic might have worked if we had stayed calm?
Couldn't I have given you a better life?

possible interpretation: would any good have came upon us if we have passed over those opportunities waiting for better time?

any experient English speaker would interpret it like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think Lines and 2 are saying that by procrastinating, the speaker and the listener failed to take advantage of certain opportunities. They were never sure if it was the right time to try or not.

Lines 3 and 4 are saying that amazing things could have happened if they didn't let their emotions flare up. If the two of them had stayed calm, the speaker would have been able to better help the listener.